# How To Make An Activity Stop Showing Permanently on Button Click

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application in which there is a tutorial that includes a form where a person has to fill in some information so that the app can function properly.
The only problem I have is that I want the tutorial to stop showing on Button Click.

I don't want to have a situation where the user will accidentally close the app during the tutorial and will never get the opportunity to fill the form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: **I don't want to have a situation where the user will accidentally close the app** , worry not, because neither the **user** nor the people **here** can never ever **accidently open** the app, without code description :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very very possible and a bit easy to implement, in your activity you have to use a feature known as *sharedpreferences* ..it stores a Boolean value let's say 0 for an activity/view and you can set onclick listener to change the value of the sharedpreference boolean to 1, so android stores this value in your app as default so activity cannot showup again.

Check out this tutorial to get started
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: The information was very useful in more ways than you can imagine. You have really saved me a heck load of stress.

Comment: I would vote for you but i don't have enough reputation

Comment: Hahaha, pleasure to help bro

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable code on button click like this:-

```
 final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id); //Find the relevant Button
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         return; // NO-OP
     }
```

Comment: I think the code is a little too simple and may cause a few errors and issues on other versions of android as the app will also need to use an intent to go to a new activity once the tutorial is done.